# Apply effect on window in Flex, Air, AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, window, effect

I'm looking to animate a popup window using the  effect.

The problem is that the effect is applied to the content of the popup window, not the popup window itself (including the title bar, minimize, maximize buttons etc)

Have a look at the result here..

[image: Result of the animation]

My code is really simple and logically, should work if it is possible to animate a window.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import comps.MyWin;

            [Bindable]
            private var _win:MyWin;

            protected function openPopup():void
            {
                _win = new MyWin();
                _win.width = 300;
                _win.height = 300;
                _win.open();    
            }

            protected function animatepopup():void
            {
                MyEffect.play();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:Move id="MyEffect" xFrom="{_win.x}" xTo="{_win.x + 150}" target="{_win}"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:Button label="Open" click="openPopup()"/>

    <s:Button label="Animate" click="animatepopup()"/>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to target the object's [`NativeWindow`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html) instance in order to move and resize the object.

Thus, replace `_win.myProperty` with `_win.stage.nativeWindow.myProperty`:

```
<s:Move id="MyEffect" xFrom="{_win.stage.nativeWindow.x}" xTo="{_win.stage.nativeWindow.x + 150}" target="{_win.stage.nativeWindow}"/>
```

Then, the animation will affect the `NativeWindow` and not the internals of the window.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.. I have the following error "unable to bind to property 'stage' on class 'comps::MyWin'"

Even trying to set the target afterward in AS3, I have the following error "Property transformX not found on flash.display.NativeWindow and there is no default value."

Any clue? THANKS!

Comment: Might have to not use the effect and use a different method of transitioning. Try `<s:Animate/>`.

Comment: Try testing out actual code by setting `_win.stage.nativeWindow.x = 250;` in the `animatepopup()` method. Then, you'll know that what you're attempting to do does actually work in theory :)

Comment: It works. NOTE that I had to set the target programmatically before calling the effect in order for the effect to work. So '<s:Animate id="MyEffect" target="{_win.stage.nativeWindow}">' will not work. I had to do 'MyEffect.target="_win.stage.nativeWindow"' and then "MyEffect.play()". Thanks!!!!